# OpenCL performance issue on GPU

Tags: raspberry-pi, opencl, raspberry-pi3

I'm using OpenCL to optimize some code in Raspberry Pi GPU (Videocore IV).
I'm using VC4CL implementation which offers a maximum work group size of 12.

However, with simple kernels like summing two arrays, the performance of GPU is much worst than CPU's.

For example, for the following kernel:

```
#define GLOBAL_SIZE 12
#define LOCAL_SIZE  1
#define WIDTH       12*12*12
#define NTIMES      1000

__attribute__ ((reqd_work_group_size(LOCAL_SIZE, LOCAL_SIZE, LOCAL_SIZE)))
__kernel void int_sum(global const uint* A, global const uint* B, global uint* C)
{
  int g_id0 = get_global_id(0);
  int g_id1 = get_global_id(1);
  int g_id2 = get_global_id(2);

  int index = g_id0 + g_id1 * GLOBAL_SIZE + g_id2 * GLOBAL_SIZE * GLOBAL_SIZE;

  for(int k = 0; k < NTIMES; k++)
    C[index + k * WIDTH] = A[index + k * WIDTH] + B[index + k * WIDTH];
}
```

where two arrays of 1e6 positions are summed, CPU's performance is much better...
I've tried to change workgroup to one dimensional and also to use other combinations like (6x6x6 -> global size, 2x2x2 -> local size).
Any hint of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try unrolling loop just in case compiler doesn't. Then use pipelining inside the unrolled loop, to hide memory latencies. CPU shouldn't be better if GPU is using all pipelines. How does it access main memory? Are the buffers aligned to 1024 or 4096 or something that OpenCL implementation better at accessing? Are you counting buffer copy timings too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular GPU, but a few things that stand out as possible red flags in your code:

- This is integer ALU heavy code rather than using floating-point operations. Many GPUs are not optimised for this at all.
- I wouldn't rely on the compiler optimising the array offset calculations; a particularly stupid compiler might emit 3 integer multiplications for `C[index + k * WIDTH] = A[index + k * WIDTH] + B[index + k * WIDTH];` on each loop iteration. I'd keep the offset in a variable and add to it on each iteration, no multiply required.
- The 1000-iteration for loop generally stands out as a potential source of better parallelism. Many GPUs perform badly with long-running kernels.
- The memory access patterns seem sub-optimal. Try to arrange things such that adjacent work items in a group access adjacent memory locations. 2x2x2 local size seems like a particularly poor choice for that. Have you tried 12x1x1?
- Why are you even arranging the work items in this way? It looks like you're literally calculating `C[i] = A[i] + B[i]` for `i = 0..1000*12*12*12`. How about writing your kernel as exactly that and submitting 1728000 work items in one dimension? That saves on all the complicated index calculations.

If you can get any kind of feedback from the drivers what the GPU is bound by (ALU, memory loads, thread scheduling, etc.) that's going to help a lot with choosing where to look for ways to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
[Here](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL/wiki/Limitations) are the limitations of the driver that I'm using.

I've tried 12x1x1, but it does not get better...
How can I get 1728000 work items if this GPU driver is limited at 12x12x12 work group size? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndréAguiar Group size limits have nothing to do with global work size.

Comment: Unfortunately [here](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL/wiki/NotSupported) is said that this driver does not support work groups with more than 12 work items. I'm I right?

Comment: I experienced this because everytime I set `global work size` more than 12 I get `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`.

Comment: @AndréAguiar Please share your code where you enqueue the kernel and select the work size.

Comment: Sorry, I got it now... The problem was that the global work group size that I was choosing was not multiple of the local group size. Now, I can choose a bigger work size and use the 12 QPUs. I will see if this works better.

Comment: I followed your advice and to sum two vectors with a size of 3796416 I have a workgroup size of 3796416 and a localsize of 12, so I use all the cores.
The kernel:
```
#define GLOBAL_SIZE 3796416
#define LOCAL_SIZE    12

__kernel void float_sum(__global const float* A, __global const float* B, global float* C) 
{
  int id = get_global_id(0);
  C[id] = A[id] + B[id];
}
This takes 1.6 secs, while CPU takes 0.3 secs...
To execute the kernel I do:
` queueu.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, 0, NDRange(3796416), NDRange(12), &ev_list, &ev);  `

Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: @AndréAguiar From [The performance constraints page you mentioned](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL/wiki/Performance), "The VC4C compiler supports scalar and vector-types with 2, 4, 8 or 16 elements. Since a QPU is a 16-way virtual SIMD, 16-element vectors yield the best performance." So I would try with `float16` vector data types (and `uint16` to compare integer performance).

Comment: @AndréAguiar I would also suggest not specifying a group size at all. As you're not using local memory, you don't actually care about groups, so the driver might be better able to distribute the work.

Answer (score 1):

Other than what everyone else has said in comments, [according to the RPi's OpenCL implementation author,](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194952) the GPU "memory access speed" (CPU-GPU memory copy ?) is much slower than the CPU. So an "arithmetically light" kernel like array sum will be limited by memory bandwidth, and can be much slower than on CPU. Plus the theoretical GPU GFlops isn't that much higher than the GPU's (24 vs 6).

Unless you have some *very* computationally heavy kernels which can also be fully vectorized, you might find using the GPU is simply not worth it.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll try some heavier kernels!
Thank you.